# Creating entity type using console doesn't work

Tags: 8, entities, console

I've installed Drupal 8.5.4 and followed these two steps to create a module and an entity type:

1. Ran `drupal gm` and filled in the info
2. Ran `drupal geco` and filled in the info (No bundles, No translation, No revisions)
3. Ran `drush en mynewmodulename`
4. Ran `drush re`

Out of the box, refreshing the Drupal main page throws an error complaining that the route is not found.

I had to manually create the module route file and fill it with all the paths from the entity generated files in order to pass the error and get the main page to render.

Now I am getting entity type not exist error.

e.g. routing entries I have added to mynewmodule.routing.yml

```
entity.mynewmodule_myentityname.add_form:
  path: '/mynewmodule/myentityname/add'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: mynewmodule_myentityname.add
    _title: 'Add myentityname'
  requirements:
    _entity_create_access: 'mynewmodule_myentityname'
```

I expected the entity forms and list page to work straightaway after creating it using Drupal console.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I've also noticed that there is no table created in the database for the new entity.

Comment: Obviously there is something wrong, because normally the entity routes are built automatically (look for the handler "route_provider" in the annotations of your entity class). Did you check the error log?

Comment: The router provider is referring to one of the generated classes that extends `AdminHtmlRouteProvider` and implements `getRoutes` and `getSettingsFormRoute`. Is this class supposed to replace the routing yml? If yes why is it not working?

Comment: When you say log, do you mean the apache error log?

Comment: Yes, exactly, route provider replaced in the early days of D8 the routing yaml for entity routes. I just ran step 1 - 3 in Drupal Console 1.8, this takes only a few seconds and I get a new entity without errors and all routes are accessible from the UI. I don't know what is wrong with your site, but since you generate a lot of php code, check for php errors in Drupal watchdog and the apache error log.

Comment: error log showing the same errors I am seeing in the browser (I have debug turned on). When I remove routing yml I cannot even navigate to the admin pages. `Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\RouteNotFoundException: "Route "mymodule_myentity.settings" does not exist." at /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php line 202`

Comment: OK, this is not news, we already know that routes are missing. The question is why, look for errors while building and installing the new module.

Comment: running `drush en` and `drush re` comes with no errors, browsing the site for the first time after rebuild comes with only that error.

Comment: Try a different module name and entity id so you are sure you have a fresh install of the module when you run `drush en`. Or a fresh test site. I'm afraid without error message or other details there is nothing to answer here, because the two console commands are correct.

Comment: I tried to create new dummy module and new dummy entity and it works
I am guessing the problem is that I got the word 'Class' into my entity name. Any idea why is this an issue?